# Access denied while update Active Directory object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have an application (MVC4) with windows authentication against Active Directory.
After user is logged into (via browser login dialog), he gets page with his data where he can update it, for example emial address.

After user clicks save button, he gets 'Access is denied' error, but he has appropriate privilages in Active Directory.

I save the user data with code like this:

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry (path))
{
    SetEntityPropertyValue(de, "mail", user.Email);
    de.CommitChanges();
}
```

But, if I pass user and password of this logged user, like this:

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry (path, user, password))
{
    SetEntityPropertyValue(de, "mail", user.Email);
    de.CommitChanges();
}
```

it works. What's wrong? 
How to get user credentials from windows authentication for passing them to DirectoryEntry() method if this not happend automatically?

I didn't write earlier but IIS and AD runs on different machines.

Comment: xiyal, did you ever find an answer?  I am battling the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're authenticating with Active Directory initially using the IIS application pool identity which does not have enough permissions to write to Active Directory, but does have enough to read items from AD. Instead, I think you're looking for [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.ASPX), which will make the application run as the authenticated Windows user.

Try adding this to your web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Granted, that will require the impersonated Windows user to have enough permission to write to Active Directory as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I've tried set impersonate earlier with no success. The IIS and AD runs on different machines and when I use impersonate, then I can't authenticate - login dialog box displays over and over :/

Comment: Booth are in the same domain.

Comment: @xiyal Ah, I wonder if you're falling victim to the double hop problem. To get it resolved, you're probably going to need to get an Active Directory admin involved. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx and/or http://blogs.technet.com/b/taraj/archive/2009/01/29/checklist-for-double-hop-issues-iis-and-sql-server.aspx